# how to access the value attribute of a select tag in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the value attribute of the options of the select...
here is my html

```
<select ng-model = "selectedElement">
 <option vlaue = "1">john</option>
 <option vlaue = "2">harry</option>
 <option vlaue = "3">peter</option>
</select>
```

when I run the code

```
console.log($scope.selectedElement);
```

I got the result "john" in console
but what I expected is to get the value attribute. for eg "1" in console.
is there any way to do that.

Comment: `vlaue`???  you menat to type that as `value`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `vlaue` in the `option` which is incorrect. Use `value` that will set the value of each option and gives you that value on `$scope.selectedElement`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <select ng-model="selectedElement">
    <option value="1">john</option>
    <option value="2">harry</option>
    <option value="3">peter</option>
  </select>
  selected value is {{selectedElement}}
</div>
```

Comment: i am sorry bt I do not find the difference between your code and my code. could you explain in detail

Comment: I have `value` in the `option` element and not `vlaue` which you have in your `option` element @JBSnJohn

Comment: I am sooo sorry for my foolish mistake but in my real code I have written value..actually I have used      ng-options="x for (y, x) in districts". something like this.. bt when I see in the inspector of my browser it shows value but in real I am not getting the value.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this code as well.
Define your select box data as an array.

```
$scope.Fruits = [{
            Id: 1,
            Name: 'Apple'
        }, {
            Id: 2,
            Name: 'Mango'
        }, {
            Id: 3,
            Name: 'Orange'
        }];
```

Then define a function in your controller page.

```
      $scope.GetValue = function (fruit) {
            var fruitId = $scope.ddlFruits;
            var fruitName = $.grep($scope.Fruits, function (fruit) {
                return fruit.Id == fruitId;
            })[0].Name;
            $window.alert("Selected Value: " + fruitId + "\nSelected Text: " + fruitName);
        }
```

And last add the select tag in your html.

```
       <select ng-model="ddlFruits" ng-options="fruit.Id as fruit.Name for fruit in Fruits track by fruit.Id"
        ng-change="GetValue()">
    </select>
```

Try with this code.Hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="cart.fruit" ng-options="state as state.name for state in shelf"></select>
<br/>
<tt>Cost & Fruit selected: {{cart.fruit}}</tt>
```

Try above code.